# Vinyl Sticker on Guitar Body

Tags: guitar, instruments, maintenance

I have a vinyl stick that I really want to put on one of my guitars (I have one acoustic guitar and one electric guitar), but I'm concerned that it could either affect the sound or damage the body.
Would it be better to put the sticker on an electric guitar or an acoustic guitar? Where would be the best spot to place the sticker w/o causing problems but still having it be visible?

Comment: Sure there was a similar question a couple of years ago.

Comment: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/34028/will-putting-decals-stickers-on-my-acoustic-guitar-affect-the-sound-and-if-so may be useful, as may http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15486/putting-stickers-on-an-acoustic-guitar.

Comment: it *might* vibrate if it is not completely adhered. THis would sound like a buzz or e.g. playing cards on a bicycle wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't do much to the sound.  If it's a cheap guitar, go ahead.  If it's a good one, just don't.  Put a badge on the strap instead, or a sticker on the guitar case.  A sticker can't be THAT important.